# easy react/babeljs question about returning props inside function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm learning a udemy course and in it we create this which is a function that takes a component and a class name as the arguments and returns a wrapped JSX having the `WrappedComponent` nested inside a `<div>`.

**This is going to be real easy but I don't understand the syntax for `props => ()`**. Why do we use the props just after return statement? I understand that inside `( )` is the JSX to return. Maybe someone can easily explain why the props is there and how it gets handled?

```
import React from 'react';

const withClass = (WrappedComponent,className) => {
   return props => (
     <div className={className}>
      <WrappedComponent/>
     </div>
   );
};

export default withClass;
```

Comment: You are not returning props, you are returning a function that accepts props and returns a React element

Comment: @samsonthehero i see. thanks

Comment: This looks like a factory pattern to wrap a div with a class around your component? A Component can be expressed as a simple function as simple as: 
const Exampe = () => <div>hi</div>. As in your example, you are not accessing any props, you could as well write "return () =>" instead.

Comment: I recommend, as good practice, to always deconstruct your props e.g. const Example = ({ someVar }) => <div>{someVar}</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example what you copied is a common react pattern called HOC (Higher Order Component). What happens here is the following we have a function which takes a component as an argument ( WrappedComponent ) and we are returning a definition of a new component which will wrap our `WrappedComponent`. You could wrote the following as well

```
const withClass = (WrappedComponent,className) => {
   return class extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return(
        <div className={className}>
         <WrappedComponent/>
        </div>
      )
     }
   } 
};
```

So basically the syntax `props => ()` is just a way to define a new component. It is worth to mention that the syntax itself is used to declare an arrow function.